# Building a Mosaic Dataset with rasters that are not georeferenced. Whats the workflow?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, georeferencing, mosaic

I have 68 aerial jpegs that I would like to use in a Mosaic Dataset. They have not been georeferenced. My question is in regards to whether I should georeference them and then rectify and save them in a new folder where I will add later to the Mosaic Dataset, or create a geodatabase, drag all the jpegs into the geodatabase, georeference (rectify?), and then create a Mosaic Dataset inside the same geodatabase.

I noticed that the original file size of the jpegs is around 30 mbs and when rectified creates a 500 mb Tif! Will these sizes be too large to work with when added to a Mosaic Dataset?

I'm using ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: YMMV, but we took all our rasters out of geodatabases to improve performance and prevent db bloat.

Comment: In addition to @recurvata 's comment, do not rectify the rasters as long as you have no solid reason (please see [this link](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/12/14/georeferencing-should-i-update-or-rectify/)), just update.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Georeference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Fundamentals_of_georeferencing_a_raster_dataset/009t000000mn000000/)
2. [Create geodatabase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018s0000000m000000)
3. [Mosaic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000098000000)